# Why is this traversal drawn clockwise in The Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol II Fig 18-5?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, vector-fields, textbook-erratum

In [Vol II Chapter 3](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_03.html) Fig 3-10 of The Feynman Lectures on Physics we are shown a traversal of the perimeter of a square lying in the XY plane.  That is, with the Z axis pointing out of the page. The direction of traversal is counterclockwise.

[image]

In [Vol II 18](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_18.html) Fig. 18-3 we see that the moving charge sheet results in a current in the positive Y direction.

[image]

In Fig 18-5 we are looking at the ZX plane with the positive Y axis pointing out of the page, with a **clockwise traversal** shown.  Shouldn't a traversal around a positively oriented normal be counterclockwise?

[image]

The same situation is depicted in Fig 18-6

[image]

Notice that this is the opposite of that shown in Fig 3-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the arrows around the $\Gamma$ surfaces are meant to indicate "circulation", rather than traversal.  The portions parallel to the X direction would be cancelled out by the oppositely directed circulation of an adjacent surface.  This is not explained in the text.